# Application Performance improving using visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, roslyn, code-analysis

I'm working on a large application with great number of classes containing properties with getters making calls to the database. These properties are used everywhere in foreach loops and in grids rows data source binding. Is there an efficient way (technique or tool) to find all these properties so I can optimise them and include them in my final report? - Something like: Give me all properties that make a Database call in their getters and are used in a foreach loop or bound to data source of a grid rows.

Thanks

Comment: I tend to use tools like "miniprofiler" to keep an eye on what is actually happening at runtime when using a system (I can see **exactly** what ran to generate this page on Stack Overflow, for example - every SQL hit, every redis hit, every ... everything) - great for spotting n+1 and other similarly chatty problems. But that's runtime, not a build / code-analysis tool. Edit: irony: it looks like I'm running duplicated SQL in "add comment" (see the "!") https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxrZO.png